# graphql mesh execute query programatically

Tags: graph, graphql-mesh

I am using the graphql-mesh as gateway to connect and get data from some internal resources. I want to use this mesh query programatically so from other rest handler I can execute any query from my mesh gateway. Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mesh's execute function, as shown [here](https://www.graphql-mesh.com/docs/guides/mesh-sdk#executing-queries-programmatically)